# Can we stack the range column chart in apexchart?

Tags: javascript, charts, apexcharts

I'm using apexchart in one of my projects.
Currently I'm using **range column chart**.
https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/column-charts/range-column-chart/

Is there a way to stack the data points of two different series into one as the one in the anychart [sample](https://playground.anychart.com/docs/v8/samples/BCT_Range_Column_Chart_06) ?

[image]

To something similar to the one in anychart
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible vertically but you can check if timeline chart with mixed series could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apexcharts stacked bars:

https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/bar-charts/stacked/

Comment: But these are not ranged right ?
It seems currently that's not available in apexchart